# Как сделать автокомплит в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qplaintextedit, qcompleter

Вот пробовал таким способом заставить автокомплит (`QCompleter`) работать.

Но в появившемся окне в поле ввода не выскакивает предложение автозаполнения, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

```
import syntax
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QLabel,QGridLayout, QWidget, QLineEdit,QCompleter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
editor = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
editor.setStyleSheet("""QPlainTextEdit{
font-family:'Consolas'; 
  color: #ccc; 
  background-color: #2b2b2b;}""")
strList = ['Python', 'PyQt5', 'Qt', 'Django', 'QML']
completer = QCompleter(strList, editor)
highlight = syntax.PythonHighlighter(editor.document())        
editor.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [PyQt5 QTextEdit auto completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956693/pyqt5-qtextedit-auto-completion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс [**QPlainTextEdit**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) предоставляет виджет, который используется для редактирования и отображения обычного текста.

Класс [**QCompleter**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#details) обеспечивает завершение на основе модели элемента.
Вы можете использовать `QCompleter` для обеспечения автоматического завершения в любом виджете *Qt*, например `QLineEdit` и `QComboBox`. 
Когда пользователь начинает вводить слово, `QCompleter` предлагает возможные способы завершения слова на основе списка слов. 
Список слов предоставляется как `QAbstractItemModel`.

> void QCompleter::[**activated**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#activated)(const QString &text)
>
> Этот сигнал отправляется, когда элемент в popup() активируется 
> пользователем (щелкнув или нажав клавишу возврата).

---

**main.py**:

```
import syntax
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, 
    QWidget, QLineEdit, QCompleter, QPlainTextEdit)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt


class PlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):           
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QPlainTextEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.multipleCompleter = None

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
        if not self.multipleCompleter:
            return
        c = self.multipleCompleter
        
        if self.toPlainText() == "":                                    
            return
        c.setCompletionPrefix(self.cursorWord(self.toPlainText()))      
        
        if len(c.completionPrefix()) < 1:
            c.popup().hide()
            return
        c.complete()

    def cursorWord(self, sentence):
        p = sentence.rfind(" ")
        if p == -1:
            return sentence
        return sentence[p + 1:]

    def insertCompletion(self, text):                             
        p = self.toPlainText().rfind(" ")                                 
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        if p == -1:
            self.setPlainText(text)                                   
        else:
            self.setPlainText(self.toPlainText()[:p+1]+ text)   
        self.setTextCursor(cursor) 

    def setMultipleCompleter(self, completer):
        self.multipleCompleter = completer
        self.multipleCompleter.setWidget(self)
        completer.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


def main():
    app    = QApplication([])
    editor = PlainTextEdit()        
    editor.setStyleSheet("""QPlainTextEdit{
      font-family:'Consolas'; 
      color: #ccc; 
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color: #2b2b2b;}""")
      
    strList   = [ 'def', 'Python', 'PyQt5', 'Qt', 'Django', 'QML']
    completer = QCompleter(strList, editor)
    highlight = syntax.PythonHighlighter(editor.document())

    completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    editor.setMultipleCompleter(completer)

    editor.setGeometry(400, 50, 800, 600)
    editor.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, так работает, благодарю за помощь, но конечно один минус есть по нажатию Entern слово не вставляется, надо обязательно нажать мышкой, возможно в Windows работает, но на Linux/OSX нет:(

Comment: Вопрос звучал - "Как сделать". Я предоставил один из вариантов.