# Живой поиск по БД, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, поиск, sqlite3

У меня есть программа с графическим интерфейсом, там есть строка "Поиск". У меня есть обычный поиск строки по части слова, но надо сделать как в гугле, чтобы при вводе нового символа с клавиатуры сразу проверяло на совпадения. Мой код выглядит так:

```
def poisk():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mybd.sqlite')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    m=input('Введите ')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT product FROM blog WHERE product LIKE '%' || ? || '%'",(m,))
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    if res:
       print(res[0][0])
    else:
       print('Такого товара нет!')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Какой графический интерфейс? (Библиотека)

Comment: если PyQt5 то [по примеру можете сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795990/255866)

Comment: У меня Tkinter, может кто поможет?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Tkinter - How to create a combo box with autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298159/tkinter-how-to-create-a-combo-box-with-autocompletion)