# Как сделать autocompleter в PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, qcompleter

Разбираюсь как сделать `autocompleter` в PyQt5. 
Вот нашел такой 
[вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795990/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2-pyqt5) и пытаюсь установить `setStyleSheet` для
 `QCompleter`.

Так сделать нельзя , тогда  [погуглил.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585184/qt-qcompleter-cant-have-its-size-set)
И переписал код так:

```
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...

    completer = QCompleter(strList, editor)

    popup = QAbstractItemView()
    
    completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
    completer.setPopup(popup)
    editor.setMultipleCompleter(completer)

    ...
```

И получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Comment: Нельзя создать объект абстрактного класса. Выберите любой из подходящих наследников

Comment: А какие у него наследники я пытался написать сам не получилось :)?

Comment: Смотрите в https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html на `Inherited By`. Это и будут его *прямые* наследники Кст, а почему бы у `completer` не запросить `popup()` у не применить к нему стиль (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html#setPopup)?

Comment: #gil9red Спасибо тоже!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны использовать delegate:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class CompleterDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(CompleterDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QColor("yellow")
        option.palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtGui.QColor("red"))
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(20, 20, 200, 40)

        completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(self)
        self.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)
        model = QtCore.QStringListModel()
        completer.setModel(model)
        delegate = CompleterDelegate(self.lineEdit)
        completer.popup().setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        completer.popup().setItemDelegate(delegate)
        self.get_data(model)

    def get_data(self,model):
        model.setStringList(["one", "two", "three", "four", "python", "pyqt"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(500, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]